# Redirect subdomain URL to URL subdirectory on Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

We've created a subdomain via Route 53 on AWS that points to an external server. We now want to redirect that traffic back to the main domain, but to a subdirectory.

shop.mydomain.com would redirect to mydomain.com/shop

DNS doesn't like resolving subdirectories like that... any suggestions?

Answer (score 19):

If I understand correctly, you want ALL requests to `shop.mydomain.com` to redirect to `mydomain.com/shop`.

In that case I recommend using S3's "Redirection Rules".

Create a bucket in S3 called `shop.mydomain.com`. Open the bucket properties and set the bucket to "Enable Website Hosting". Then select the "Edit Redirection Rules" option.

[image: AWS Console Edit Redirection Rules Screenshot]

We now need to define a redirection rule that matches every request, and redirects it to `mydomain.com/shop`

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Redirect>
      <Protocol>https</Protocol>
      <HostName>mydomain.com</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>shop/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
      <HttpRedirectCode>301</HttpRedirectCode>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

This rule will match every request and redirect it.

For more info on routing rules, check out the official docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html#configure-bucket-as-website-routing-rule-syntax

Now, you need to configure `shop.mydomain.com` in Amazon Route 53 as an `ALIAS` record pointing at the bucket you just created, `shop.mydomain.com`.

That's it - Enjoy!

Comment: Is there any way to have an Amazon S3 bucket's subfolder redirect to an external server? E.g. I'm trying to get mydomain.com/blog to forward to an external Wordpress server but KEEP the domain as mydomain.com/blog. I know this can be done with a subdomain but I'd prefer to use a subfolder. I have my Wordpress on another separate server because S3 hosting doesn't support WP (CGI/PHP/etc.)

Comment: I believe your best bet is to use CloudFront. It supports different routing rules so you can points `mydomain.com/blog` to your wordpress blog, and everything else to your S3 bucket. Since cloudfront proxies requests, your users won't see any separation - everything will look like a single site under mydomain.com

Comment: @secretmike This sounds like an interesting option. Can you post more information about how to do this, or perhaps links to a suggested solution?

Comment: I would also note that I was required to fill out the `Index Document:` field. Since I was trying to redirect to a folder with no specific document (ie `example.com/sub/folder/`), I just entered `index.html` and it worked

Comment: I think [this link regarding origins and behaviors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567994/multiple-cloudfront-origins-with-behavior-path-redirection?rq=1) can also help.
Just to emphasize the suggested solution, it's based on the fact that you can define several sources (ELB wrapped around some EC2, S3) that co-exists and pick between them with several behaviors acting as routing.

Comment: What I got doing that was the redirect to `mydomain.com/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop`.