# Redirect subfolder URL but keep original domain name

Tags: web-services, redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Following below URLs, I successfully redirect website  http://www.example.com (I bought from AWS Route 53, real domain name is replaced) to http://abc.wix.com/xyz/ via `www.example.com.au.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com`

Refer:  [Set up DNS based URL forwarding in Amazon Route53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115799/set-up-dns-based-url-forwarding-in-amazon-route53)  and [Redirect subdomain URL to URL subdirectory on Amazon AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728558/redirect-subdomain-url-to-url-subdirectory-on-amazon-aws)

Redirection rules:

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Redirect>
            <Protocol>http</Protocol>
            <HostName>abc.wix.com</HostName>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>xyz/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
            <HttpRedirectCode>301</HttpRedirectCode>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

The problem is, when I click http://www.example.com, it redirects the url to **http://abc.wix.com/xyz/** in browser and show the web content.

What I need is: in the browser, should be always showed as  **http://www.example.com** , but contents are in http://abc.wix.com/xyz/.

Comment: this isn't an S3 problem; the destination server would need to respond as example.com. Alternately, you can load the contents in a frame or load the body html from example.com and load the rest of the assets from wix.com.