# AWS Redirect Subdomain to Subfolder in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, redirect

First of all my stack is a very simple one on AWS. I have these three services:

- S3 Bucket hosting my website
- CloudFront pointing to my S3 Bucket
- Route 53 pointing to CloudFront

So, what I'm trying to do is to redirect a subdomain to a subfolder inside my S3 bucket. Something like this: `shop.mydomain.com` -> `mydomain.com/shop`.

I tried S3 Bucket redirect rules, mentioned in this answer [Redirect subdomain URL to URL subdirectory on Amazon AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728558/redirect-subdomain-url-to-url-subdirectory-on-amazon-aws) but what I got was `shop.mydomain.com` -> `mydomain.com/shop/shop/shop/...`

---

EDIT:

My S3 Bucket is in "Host Website" mode, and this is the redirect config I tried to use:

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Redirect>
            <Protocol>https</Protocol>
            <HostName>mydomain.com</HostName>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>shop/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
            <HttpRedirectCode>301</HttpRedirectCode>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

My CloudFront is pointing correctly to the bucket, and also the route 53 is pointing correctly to CloudFront. In that case `mydomain.com` is working fine.

Can someone please help me on that?

Comment: Could you post your config?

Comment: For sure @jellycsc I'll update the question right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

You CloudFront configuration needs to define another distribution what will be the root file/folder.

The CloudFront distribution should point to `mydomain.com/shop`. Create another distribution and make sure to point to the S3 Bucket public URL and don't forget to put the path to the subfolder there. Do not forget to put the right CNAME when creating the distribution, the CNAME must be the subdomain you're using, e.g. `shop.mydomain.com` without this it won't work.

Now, you need to create a new entry on Route 53 and point it to the new CloudFront distribution. So, create an entry with your subdomain and select CloudFront link to link with your new distribution. If everything ran correctly your distribution will appear there.

That's it.

Comment: I think you're suggesting me to create another distribution on CloudFront and point it to the S3 Bucket subfolder right? Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, exactly, one distr for each subfolder that you want to use as root element

Comment: Happy to say that this worked man, thanks a lot, but we need to edit your answer. Also, happy to see that you're brazilian too hahha. Many thanks.

Comment: Haha, glad to hear that it worked, and thanks for the answer improve